# How do I get the site source code as  a registered user using c#?

Tags: c#

i downloaded a sourcecode of a site,but i downloaded it i saw it identify my program as a guest,i search at google and figure out that i can send a cookie when i "ask" the source code.
that what i have managed to do and it still dont identify me as register user:

```
CookieContainer cj = new CookieContainer();
string all = "";
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
req.CookieContainer = cj;
HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
CookieCollection cs=cj.GetCookies(req.RequestUri);
CookieContainer cc = new CookieContainer();
cc.Add(cs);
req.CookieContainer = cc;
StreamReader read = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
all = read.ReadToEnd();
read.Close();             
return all;
```

what is wrong here?
tyvm for help:)

Answer (score 0):

If the site uses HTTP Authentication, you can try the following:

```
req.PreAuthenticate=true;
req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

---

If there is a custom login form instead, you will need to submit the data in the same way as the browser did. There's some info on sending data using the WebRequest class here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx

You'll probably want to change this bit:

```
string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";
```

To something like this:

```
string postData = "username=MyUsername&password=MyPassword";
```

Substitute "username" and "password" with the names of the actual fields on the login form.